# How to Get Specific Line from a ListBox Based on Integer

Tags: c#, string, listbox, integer, int

I have a very basic listbox here, and I want to get the text from a specific line, based on listbox1.items.count; since that is an integer

How do get the line corresponding to that integer (per se, line number), and store that line of the list box into the string RecentPlayer?

```
Ex.

 Line #    ListBox Contents

 Line 0    Some String

 Line 1    Some Other

 Line 3    Something Else
```

Comment: please provide your code that populates your listbox

Comment: its really lengthy.......

Comment: but here's a single line of it `playerList.Items.Add(player.Info.Rank.Name + " - " + player.Name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string value = playerList.Items[index].ToString();
```

Comment: I had just figured out how to do the ToString() option right as it was updated :P